# I want my dropdown menu from a nav-bar to push the content below it

Tags: html, css

I want my dropdown menu with `position: absolute` to move the content in `div#main` 136px down. It didnt work using `nav ul li:hover #main {margin-top: 136px;}`. I want to solve the problem via html/css if possible! Site:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #327ead;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #c4c4c4;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c4c4c4;
}
b {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
div#head {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  height: 53px;
}
nav {
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  width: 930px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #327ead;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #327ead;
}
nav ul ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: none;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  width: 400px;
  height: 136px;
  text-align: left;
}
nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.news1 {
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}
ul.news2 {
  margin: 4px 0 0 400px;
}
ul.news3 {
  margin: 4px 0 0 800px;
  width: 130px;
}
div#main {
  width: 930px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #c4c4c4;
  text-align: justify;
}
div#mostrecentnews {
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
    
    <nav>
    
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">News</a>
                <ul class="news1">
                    <li><b>Today's News</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#">content...</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">content...</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">content...</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Browse More...</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="news2">
                    <li><b>Top Weekly News</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#">content...</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">content...</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">content...</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Browse More...</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="news3">
                    <li><b>History</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#">May</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">April</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">March</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Browse More...</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
       </ul>
      
    </nav>
  
</div>

<div id="main">
        
        <img src="data/RL-Takumi.jpg">
    
        <div id="mostrecentnews">
        
            <b>Welcome to RocketLeague-Data.com!</b><br>
       content...content...content...content...content...content...content...content...content...content...content...
        
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Since #main isn't a descendant of nav, your selector (`nav ul li:hover #main`) won't work since those spaces mean descendants. Also, since the content getting "pushed down" in the menu is absolutely positioned, it isn't in the same flow as the content in #main, so you can't achieve what you want using such CSS. I would try playing around with setting `overflow: hidden;` on menu elements (with a height set) and then, on hover, changing to `overflow: visible` and `height: auto`. Good luck.

Comment: isnt margin considered to be the distance it moves away from top/right...? So shouldnt `margin-top: 136px` when hovering over an li of nav move away #main 136px from the original position? I dont quite understand it.

Comment: `nav ul li:hover #main` refers to the element with ID of "main", somewhere inside a hovered li, somewhere inside a ul, somewhere inside a nav. Since <div id="main"> is not nested within the <nav> (let alone the <li>s), such a selector won't ever find a match. CSS doesn't have ways on its own of selectors like "find the #main div if its sibling nav has children with such-and-such". Does that help to clarify things?

Comment: Absolutely! So to move the content down bottom using my method it, i would need to write the whole content into a list? No thank you to that!

Comment: Complex selectors like that can manipulated with something like JavaScript, but that's extra complication, and I think if you can get creative with CSS properties like `overflow` instead of using absolute positioning, you can keep #main in the same flow as the nav, meaning that changes to nav's height should change how far #main's content is offset from the top. Hopefully I'm not confusing you further. :-)

Comment: i'll get a little research on overflow once i've slept, my first try hasnt worked, that doesnt mean it cant work. with that being said, good night and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**REFINED:**

Used JQuery:

```
var down = false;
$('#btn').hover(function () {
  if (down == true) {
    $('#main').css("margin-top", "0");
    down = false;
  } else {
    $('#main').css("margin-top", "136px");
    down = true;
  }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Popatop15/kv09oev6/)

Comment: Updated my answer using jquery